# How to diagnose the problem when Apache at random times shows "Not Found" on the web?

Tags: centos, apache-httpd

Suppose I reload my web site 100 times by holding
down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on my keyboard.

I notice once in a while Apache throws out a

```
Not Found
```

error message.

If I refresh again, everything works normal again.

This makes it difficult to even discuss the issue. 
This makes it difficult to even diagnose the issue. 
This makes it difficult to even ask questions about the issue.

How can one diagnose the issue?

Comment: 404 errors are logged, or at least, can be logged. You can read the logs.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith your comment is an answer to this question as it is written.

Comment: This doesn't seem UNIX or Linux specific. →[Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)?

Answer (score 2):

I am writing my comment as an answer since it seems to be relevant to your case. Keyword: **logs**.

You can find logs for Apache2 at: `/var/log/apache2`. They may be in different locations according to your distribution, but this one is the most common.

Have a look at error and access logs to identify your requests. You can use `grep` to search your logs for 404 errors:

```
grep '404' /var/log/apache2 -R
```

[Have a look here for more information about Apache error logs.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html#errorlog)